# Exposing a webHttpBinding WCF service to mobile clients

Tags: silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7

I have created a very basic service operation that needs to write content to my database. This service looks like the following:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = false)]
public class myService : ImyService
{
  public MyServiceResult MyMethod(string p1, string p2)
  {
    try
    {
      // Do stuff
      MyResponseObject r = new MyResponseObject();
      r.Property1 = DateTime.Now;
      r.Property2 = "Some other data";
      return r;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

ImyService is defined as shown here:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ImyService
{
  [OperationContract]
  [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
  MyServiceResult MyMethod(string p1, string p2);
}
```

This service will be exposed to both WP7 and iPhone client applications. Because of this, I believe I need to use webHttpBinding. This has caused me to use the following settings in my web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>      
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>

  <serviceHostingEnvironment 
    aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"   
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  <services>
    <service name="myService">
      <endpoint address="" 
        behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior" 
        binding="webHttpBinding" 
        contract="ImyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Both the service and WP7 app are part of the same solution. I can successfully add a reference to the service in my application. When I run the application though, the page that references the service throws an error. The error says:

*Could not find default endpoint element that references contract 'MyServiceProxy.ImyService' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.*

What am I doing wrong? It just seems like this should be a pretty straightforward thing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you copied the file "ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" into your Windows Phone 7 project? This file is in your WCF project. Also, WP7 clients support basicHttpBinding only. So, you may see an empty "ServiceReferences.ClientConfig" file unless you switch over to basicHttpBinding