# WCF REST communication with Windows Phone

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, rest, azure

I'm having some trouble regarding a rest request sent from my Windows Phone app via RestSharp to a self hosted WCF service I have made. The request works fine in the emulator and the request returns a result but when I try to perform the request on my app on an actual device it fails and the request does not return anything.

Having done a fair amount of research I have discovered that apparently webHttpBinding is not supported on Windows Phone and therefore I need to add a **basicHttpBinding** endpoint to my **Web.config** file. However, when I try to do this I get several errors associated with having more than one endpoint and I can't seem to get any solution to successfully work with both of these. Switching the endpoint to basicHttpBinding and commenting out webHttpBinding also causes an error when I navigate to localhost:81/mywebservice.svc

```
   "System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation analyseFace to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream."
```

asking for the stream that should be attached with a request. It shows a normal help page using the original code and the same address.

**My web.config file**

```
     <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          name="AzureDiagnostics">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="servicebehavior">
          <!--<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>-->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" httpHelpPageEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restbehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="servicebehavior" name="VizageAPIWebRole.vizage">
          <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="restbehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" name="RESTEndPoint" contract="VizageAPIWebRole.Ivizage" />
          <!--<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="VizageAPIWebRole.Ivizage" />-->
        </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RestBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

**My WCF SERVICE**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Ivizage
{
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/agerecog/{auth}", Method = "POST")]
    VizageResult analyseFace(string auth, Stream dataStream);

}
```

I'm wondering if someone can help me work out what code I have to edit in my web.config to make this work for both endpoints as I haven't had any luck so far with things I've tried

Comment: Where did you read about WP7 not supporting webHttpBinding? I was under the assumption that it supported basicHttpBinding AND webHttpBinding. (Ref: Pro Windows Phone App Development book)

Comment: this guys says it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3800420/634420

Comment: and here: I am now attempting to consume the service from Windows Phone (WP7). However, as the .NET Framework hasn't quite caught up to WP7 yet, the System.ServiceModel.Web namespace is unavailable with the result that the webHttpBinding doesn't work in WP7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837330/how-do-you-configure-a-wcf-service-with-two-endpoints-to-use-a-different-listenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be a REST service, but basicHttpBinding supports SOAP. So please continue to use webHttpBinding. However, on the Windows Phone side, the WCF cannot be used, it is needed to use WebClient or HttpWebRequest to access a REST service. WCF can just help us to access a SOAP service.

In addition, you mentioned the application works fine in the emulator, so it is unlikely to be a coding issue. It would be better if you can check whether your real phone device is able to access internet. Please also make sure you're using the cloud service's address instead of 127.0.0.1. Local address will not work on a real device.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 0):

From the exception and your config - you are using simplified configuration which by default uses basicHttpBinding. You have to explicity define service end point

```
 <services>
      <service  name="WcfRest.Ivizage">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="restbehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
         contract="WcfRest.Ivizage" />
      </service>
 </services>
```

Edit: looks like webHttp is not [supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470110%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this but I get this error "System.InvalidOperationException: For request in operation analyseFace to be a stream the operation must have a single parameter whose type is Stream." when trying to access vizage.svc whe it should be the "This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service." page. Changing the service name to .vizage rather than .Ivizage shows the service page but when I then try to swap the webhttpbinding endpoint for a basic one the same error mentioned previously occurs